# css before and after line's vertical aligning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical-align 2 lines and a title. But it doesn't work correctly. My **html** code is-

```
<div class="content-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center m-0">
        <div class="our-service-head">
            <p class="our-service-title text-center">Our Services</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **style.css**:

```
.our-service-title{
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.our-service-title:before, .our-service-title:after{
    content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: super;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #FFC000;
}
```

it shows like the following output:

[image]

How can I align this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` on the pseudo element:

```css
.our-service-title{
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.our-service-title:before, .our-service-title:after{
    content:" ";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #FFC000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center m-0">
        <div class="our-service-head">
            <p class="our-service-title text-center">Our Services</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```